# How to pass the current gmail url from gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail

I  am sending a mail to Gmail account. The body contains 2 Buttons. Approve and Reject.

I am able to submit the form with Approve and reject parameters through the form action url. But I need to pass the current email URL also. But the javascript is not working inside the gmail.

Is there any way to execute the javascript inside the gmail or pass the current URL.

Jay

Comment: Executing JavaScript inside an email is something you cannot do. It's because of security considerations that gmail and all other email services block JavaScript content in their emails.

Answer (score 0):

No, because allowing Javascript would really be a security risk.
However, you can try to get the URL using the `Referer` HTTP header when that form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript in an email. You should insert the email address into the link on the server as you're sending the email. Also, remember that an anyone could submit a request on behalf of someone else just by knowing an email address.

For better security, I would include a secret identifier that you cross-check with your database to verify the requester's identity, e.g.:

http://example.com?email=hello@example.com&action=approve&id=17798bb3ab844de8b046a29a97a1ea2e

This will not protect against interception of the email, but it's as good as you can do without having the recipient log in to verify the request.